# Some Macro terms in Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

I am confused by the terms for a long time, thinking it is good to ask out what exactly do they mean:

A. syntax. B. syntax value. C. syntax object. D.s-expression E.datum (in syntax->datum)

- What's the difference between s-expression and symbol?
- What's the difference between s-expression and datum?
- What's the difference between (syntax, syntax values and syntax object) from s-expression?
- Code examples for explanation will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Syntax" is a type for representing source code in Racket, which is a wrapper around S-expression (see a [recent blog post](http://blog.racket-lang.org/2011/04/writing-syntax-case-macros.html) for details).  "Syntax value" and "syntax object" are all synonyms of this, and ni the ancient days of the `mzscheme` language functions that deal with syntax used `syntax-value` in the name.  These days we use just "syntax" more often, and for a plural form we use "syntaxes".

An "S-expression" is either a primitive piece of data that can be typed in code (symbols, numbers, strings, booleans, etc -- in Racket you could also include other types), or a list of these things.  An S-expression is therefore any nested structure of lists made of these primitive types at the fringe.  Sometimes this includes vectors too (since they can be typed in using the `#(...)` syntax) but more usually they're left out.

Finally, "datum" is another name for an S-expression, sometimes when you want to refer to the fact that it's a piece of data that has an input representation.  You can see how [R5RS](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/) introduces it: `<Datum>` may be any external representation of a Scheme object [...].  This notation is used to include literal constants in Scheme code.

As for your questions:

- What's the difference between s-expression and symbol?

  A symbols is an S-expression, an S-expression may contain symbols.
- What's the difference between s-expression and datum?

  Nothing really.  (Although some subtle intentions differences might be there.)
- What's the difference between (syntax, syntax values and syntax object) from s-expression?

  They are the representation of program syntax used by macros in racket -- they *contain* the S-expressions, but they add source location information, lexical context, syntax properties, and certificates.  See that blog post for a quick introduction.

Comment: Great answers, with these explained, I think I can go on reading that post!:)