# Why can't this macro execute?

Tags: scheme, racket

I have the following dumb test:

```
(define-syntax a
 (lambda (stx)
   (syntax-case stx ()
     [(k e s) #'(let ((show display)) (e s))])))
(a show "something")
```

Why can't this work? (The error shows in DrRacket is `expand: unbound identifier in module in: show`.

However, The following can work:

```
(define-syntax a
 (lambda (stx)
   (syntax-case stx ()
     [(k e s) 
      (with-syntax ((show (datum->syntax #'k 'show)))
        #'(let ((show display)) (e s)))])))
(a show "something")
```

Then WHY?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um, I assume that you're trying this out after reading the [blog post](http://blog.racket-lang.org/2011/04/writing-syntax-case-macros.html) I mentioned in an [earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606447/some-macro-terms-in-racket) -- but that blog post is explaining exactly this issue.  Specifically, your first example has two different `show` identifiers, one that is bound by the macro, and a *different* one that is coming from the toplevel use (and is unbound).  OTOH, in the second case you're creating a `show` with the lexical context of the user code.